# Jquery Auto suggestion click able a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm using jquery auto suggestion for search box on site http://www.4songs.pk/. Auto suggestion is working fine. I want suggestions must have click custom A tag. I want suggestion must be click able link.

HTML CODE

```
<form role="form" id="searchform" method="get" action="http://www.4songs.pk/search">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
        <div class="input-group" style="padding:10px 0;">
          <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="query" name="q" placeholder="Type Track Name and Press Search Button" required>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="searchsubmit" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</form>
```

JS Code

```
function doSomething (txt) {
    $('#selection').text ('You selected: ' + txt);
}

$('#query').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var url = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1&q=' + escape (request.term) + '&format=5&alt=json&callback=?';
        $.getJSON (url, function (json) {
            var results = [];
            $.each (json[1], function (ix, val) {
                results.push ('<a href="">'+val [0]+'</a>');
            });
            response (results);
        });
    },
    select: function(e, ui) {
        if (e.which === 13 ) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    delay:200
});
$('#query').keypress (function (ev) {
    if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
        $('#query').autocomplete ('close');
        $('#searchform').submit();
        var txt = $(this).val ();
        doSomething (txt);
        return (false);
    }
});
```

Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/nmz95e7d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your select statement to redirect url

```
 select: function(e, ui) {   
            location.href="whereyouwanttogo.com/" + ui.item.label;
        },
```

Full code

```
            <form role="form" id="searchform" method="get" action="http://www.4songs.pk/search">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                <div class="input-group" style="padding:10px 0;">
                  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="query" name="q" placeholder="Type Track Name and Press Search Button" required>                       
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
                <div id="tag_update"></div>
              </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </form>
```

JS

```
function doSomething (txt) {
    $('#selection').text ('You selected: ' + txt);
}

$('#query').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var url = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1&q=' + escape (request.term) + '&format=5&alt=json&callback=?';
        $.getJSON (url, function (json) {
            var results = [];
            $.each (json[1], function (ix, val) {
                results.push (val [0]);
            });
            response (results);
        });
    },
    select: function(e, ui) {
        //location.href="http://www.4songs.pk/search?q=" + ui;
        window.open('http://www.4songs.pk/search?q='+ ui.item.label.replace(/\s/g, "+"),'_blank');
        if (e.which === 13 ) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    delay:200
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Yes now its click-able but only one issue. The value of suggestion is not sending to new page. It is sending `[object Object]` instead of value/string of auto suggestion. I also need value/string of auto suggestion in new page without space and space should be replaced with `+` sign

Comment: I have done changes as your solution but the issue is still there you test with this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/datamodifi/2nhju0u1/1/)

Comment: @DJMHA use ui.item.label instead of ui - updated code

Comment: Thanks yes its working now but I want `space` should replace with `+` in value of suggestion. I have updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/datamodifi/2nhju0u1/2/)

Comment: And if this is an acceptable solution you should mark it as the answer with the green check.

Comment: `ui.item.label.replace(" ", "+")` replace first space only. How can we remove all spaces?

Comment: Try adding a regular expression to it. Using the global ui.item.label.replace(/\s/g, "+"); should probably work - http://jsfiddle.net/aC5ZW/

Comment: Also if the comments are helpful you can up those as well.

Comment: This one doesn't require a regular expression ui.item.label.split(' ').join('+');

Comment: Thank you. Both of above work which one is more better? Please also vote up my question if you feel it usefull